# SVG image displayed with no stretch

Tags: javascript, image, html, svg

I'm currently managing an image in HTML5 via SVG image element,

I managed to Stretch the image to the size of the width and the length of the element,
using the preserveAspectRatio="none"

But I can't find a way to do the other way around,
I want to display the image in a way so that the SVG only display the part of the image
if the image originalSize (width/height) is greater than the SVG image width and height,

Say I have an image of 700x500, and I place it on the SVG image with 200x200,
if I set the preserveAspectRatio of "none" then the image will be shrinked and become 200x200,
but what I want is to have the image displayed in the 200x200 container and doesn't shrink, instead the image will only displayed in its 200x200 part, so the rest will not be displayed because the container isn't big enough to display everything,

any idea?

Comment: Did you any of the other possible values of preserveAspectRatio?

Comment: You need to add an SVG clip and use the original method (no stretch)

Comment: I tried all values of preserveAspectRation, which is defer,none,xMin,etc. 
@Sebastian can you provide an example of that?

Comment: What doesn't happen the way you want when preserveAspectRatio is not none?

Comment: I think the picture maintain its aspect ratio, and I can see the whole picture, that's not what I want

Comment: Set a viewBox to see what you want.